# Kill port on remote server with ssh

Tags: linux, centos

I want kill specific port on remote host with below command:

```
ssh username@remoteip "fuser -k 2323/tcp"
```

but got `fuser: command not found` error. I spent hours googling for this but I could not find any possible solution.

Any idea?

my linux distribution: centos

Answer (score -1):

The error message says it all: The command `fuser` is not available.
You have to install the package `psmisc`:

```
yum install psmisc
```